# How do you perform range compression of SAR data on a 2D matrix?

Tags: image-processing, fft, radar, matched-filter, dynamic-range-compression

I am building a Matlab program to process RADARSAT-1 data that came with [this book](https://www.worldcat.org/title/digital-processing-of-synthetic-aperture-radar-data-algorithms-and-implementation/oclc/56805179).

The book describes the steps to creating SAR image as follows

[image]

I am currently implement the range compression step. For my matched filter computation I am performing a range FFT by transposing each row of the 2D matrix that represents my image first then taking the FFT of that.I understand what I need to do to perform my matched filter computation. My question is more related to how to do it in matlab on a 2D matrix. My 2D matrix  is 1536×2048 where 2048 is the number of columns which represents my fast time samples or range cells.Currently I am transposing each row so I can perform the fft on the rows of the 2D matrix in order to do the matched filter computation. Is that the right thing to do? If not what should I do?

Lastly, how can I confirm that my range compression code works?

Comment: The `fft` documentation in matlab has the answer: `fft(x, N, dim)`

Comment: Do you have a particular waveform in mind?

Comment: Yes. I am working on SAR data and compressing a linear FM chirp waveform I created. I am also wondering of the best way to confirm that the range compression worked?